# while loop on re.match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, while-loop

I have the code below and i would like the while loop part to works as the manual testing, that is it should replace any word internal character with * and leave the border character

```
    # manual testing 
    r = re.compile(r'(\w[*]*)(\w)(\w+)')
    rtext = r.sub(r'\1*\3', 'mon texste')
    print(rtext)
    rtext = r.sub(r'\1*\3', rtext)
    print(rtext)
    rtext = r.sub(r'\1*\3', rtext)
    print(rtext)
    rtext = r.sub(r'\1*\3', rtext)
    print(rtext)
    rtext = r.sub(r'\1*\3', rtext)
    print(rtext)

    text = "mon test is here"
    # Loop testing, :( it works once et doesn't iterate !!!
    while(r.match(text) is not None):
        print(text, type(r.match(text)))# just to check 
        text = r.sub(r'\1*\3',text)
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a loop here, you may use a simple regex with 3 capturing groups, and use a lambda in the `re.sub` replacement argument to replace the middle part with asterisks.

```
import re
r2 = re.compile(r"\b(\w)(\w*)(\w)\b")
res = r2.sub(lambda m: "{0}{1}{2}".format(m.group(1), "*"*len(m.group(2)), m.group(3)), 'mon texste')
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/mMedi0)

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(\w)` - Group 1: the leading word char
- `(\w*)` - Group 2: zero or more word chars
- `(\w)` - Group 3: the trailing word char
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

The replacement:

- `"{0}{1}{2}".format()` - builds the result from 3 groups
- `m.group(1)` -  the leading word char
- `"*"*len(m.group(2))` - `*` times the length of the 2nd group
- `m.group(3)` - trailing word char

Answer (score 0):

`re.match` only match characters at the beginning of string; you should use `re.search` instead. [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

So, change `r.match` in the loop condition to `r.search`.

```
while(r.search(text) is not None):
    text = r.sub(r'\1*\3',text)
print(text)
```

This code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As xmcp already said, you are using `re.match` and that always tries to match at the beginning of the string, so you would have to use `re.search` instead.

Note that your loop unnecessarily runs the regular expression very often. You could change that by storing the match object and then performing the actual replacement without regular expressions, e.g. using standard string manipulation:

```
m = r.search(text)
while m:
    inner = '*' * (m.end() - m.start() - 2)
    text = text[:m.start() + 1] + inner + text[m.end() - 1:]
    m = r.search(text)
```

This uses the indexes of the match to patch up the string.

You can also perform the replacement with a single regular expression that uses some look-behind and look-ahead magic to find inner characters:

```
>>> text = 'mon test is here'
>>> re.sub('(?<!^)(?<!\s)\w(?!\s|$)', '*', text)
'm*n t**t is h**e'
```

Comment: Thank all for your help. @poke i can do it using string and list function but the objetive is using regex in which i am completely new. So thank for your regex expression